# Not able to invoke afterPropertiesSet method from a class implementing InitializingBean

Tags: java, spring

I have developed a custom spring boot starter in which I need some initialization to happen on startup of application. I have a class which implements InitializingBean in this spring boot starter but afterPropertiesSet method is not invoked when i plug this starter to an application and start that application.
But there is class in that application(outside of my spring boot starter) which implements Initailizing bean and afterPropertiesSet of that class is invoked without any issues. Am I missing any configuration here? I need to invoke afterPropertiesSet method of Class present in my spring boot starter. Please help

Comment: In order to explain the question clearly,You should post your bean class code and the application xml file.

Comment: Also, generally, an `InitializingBean` is a bad way in initializing data as there aren't guarantees that everything has been setup already.